# How to use instagram API?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I have user id's of very few instagram public accounts . All I need to do is to get the follower count information of those accounts . In the [developer page](https://www.instagram.com/developer/) they are talking about building an app and authorizing it with the users and getting some tokens and then getting the permitted information from that account . How can I get the follower count of those accounts ? Is it possible to get it without authorization from that account? What if I want to get more information like the media and likes etc?( I couldn't find many pointers in this direction)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting number of followers of a user in instagram using Instagram API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35867158/getting-number-of-followers-of-a-user-in-instagram-using-instagram-api)

Answer (score -1):

In my practice I have not seen any api, that will provide you user personal info without token, instagram too. So you must to create login via instagram, where you will ask about some permissions from user, then if user will provide them you will be able to make requests with token and simply get media information, likes and followers. The only question is to ask user about this all permissions. It's no so hard, you need to do something like this
 1.Get user token https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=377e67cfbfe840e19a903aa5ea8dbe10&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1/&response_type=token&scope=likes+comments+relationships+public_content+follower_list
 2. then do requests, for example '/users/self/media/liked', to request this you need to provide access_token which you received in first step and signature. 
 Like a little example, you can try to look at this code https://github.com/zhorzhz/instagram_api.git. There you will find steps which I said and also some more request examples.
Hope it will help you